LAG() and LAST_VALUE in snowflake
I have a table that has data looks like:



date
qlfd_lvl
actv_ind
last_value




20230301
4
1
4


20230302
2
1
2


20230303
3
0
2


20230304
1
0
2


20230305
3
1
3


20230306
2
0
3


20230307
1
0
3



we have 2 conditions for column last_value
1.condition: actv_ind=1 then the results will same campaign qlfd_lvl value.
2.condition: actv_ind=0 then results will when previous actv_ind=1 then it will take that date qlfd_lvl value as results
(in snowflake SQL I have tried LAG and last_value but I didn't get logic )

You have a gaps and islands problem, you could use the running total to give a distinct ID to each consecutive group of rows (1 followed by zeros), then we can use window function FIRST_VALUE(), to get the desired value :
WITH cte as (
  SELECT *, SUM(actv_ind) over (ORDER BY date) AS sm
  FROM cte
)
SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(qlfd_lvl) over (PARTITION BY sm ORDER BY date ) AS LAST_VALUE
FROM cte

